# Agora SDK- Is it possible to implement peer to peer (one to one) "video chat" using Agora SDK for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, agora.io

I was wondering is there a way to implement one-to-one video chat using [**Agora SDK**](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Video-Call). I found lot of resources to implement the video call feature with establishing a channel(like group video chat). However, I couldn't find any relevant resource to implement peer-to-peer video chat.

What I have tried so far is,

I am able to implement the Group video calling by establishing a channel. Please see the below references from the Agora Documentation.

[Doc](https://www.agora.io/en/blog/build-app-with-chat-and-video-calling-android/#:%7E:text=a%20channel%20name.-,Implement%20Video%20Call%20Functionality,-In%20a%20social)

The basic setup of the video chat is below;

```
import io.agora.rtc.RtcEngine;

mRtcEngine = RtcEngine.create(context, appid, eventHandler);
mRtcEngine.setupLocalVideo(videoCanvas);
mRtcEngine.enableVideo();
***
```

> **mRtcEngine.joinChannel(token, channelName, info, uid);**

---

```
mRtcEngine.setupRemoteVideo(videoCanvas);
mRtcEngine.leaveChannel();
```

Here we have to create a channel and users should join to the same channel, then only the video call is possible. Instead of doing that I have to implement a one-to-one chat like all the popular chatting apps do. Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this blog that explains how to build a 1 to 1 video calling application using the Agora SDK: https://www.agora.io/en/blog/1-to-1-video-chat-app-on-android-using-agora/